# How to click a link with AutoIt in a frame of a frameset in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, autoit, frames, frameset

The Internet Explorer opens and nothing more happens, how can I click the link `Rubrik 1`?

autoit code:

```
#include <IE.au3>

$oIE = _IECreate("C:\Development\internet explorer frames\frames.html")
sleep(3000)
Local $oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE)
_IELinkClickByText($oFrame, "Rubrik 1")
```

html code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Frameset</title>
      </head>
      <frameset cols="200, *">
        <frame src="http://wiki.selfhtml.org/mediawiki/extensions/Selfhtml/example.php/Beispiel:FRAMESET_navigation.html" name="navigation">
        <frame src="http://wiki.selfhtml.org/mediawiki/extensions/Selfhtml/example.php/Beispiel:FRAMESET_home.html" name="inhalt">
      </frameset>
    </html>
```

scite console output:

> "C:\Users-\Downloads\autoit-v3\install\SciTe..\autoit3.exe" /ErrorStdOut "C:\Development\internet explorer frames\internet explorer frames 2.au3"
>       --> IE.au3 T3.0-2 Error from function _IELoadWait, $_IESTATUS_ClientDisconnected (-2147023179, Browser has been deleted prior to operation.)
>       "C:\Users-\Downloads\autoit-v3\install\Include\IE.au3" (671) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.:
>       Return SetError($_IESTATUS_Success, $oObject.document.parentwindow.frames.length, $oObject.document.parentwindow.frames)
>       Return SetError($_IESTATUS_Success, $oObject^ ERROR
>   Exit code: 1    Time: 4.202

[html code example source](https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/HTML/Frames#Ein_Frameset_einrichten)

Comment: This explains the issues with _IECreate https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/183032-_iecreate-and-vista-security/  Unfortunately, I can't get the rest of your code to work